# Adding JAR to SBT task runtime

Tags: scala, sbt, classpath

I’m writing an sbt task to generate some managed sources, in order to do so I’m using [fast-classpath-scanner](https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner) to extract all *sub-classes* of the [scapegoat inspection class](https://github.com/sksamuel/scapegoat/blob/26884ddce9b19f2d40e029f23d5bf55cd05debf2/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/scapegoat/Inspection.scala).

I first implemented it as a normal [scala project](https://github.com/BalmungSan/fastpath-demo/tree/91ecbad0b1929d858eb3118af33ae38561696609) and it worked, but when trying to implement it as an **SBT task** I’m having a problem, and it is that the scapegoat jar is not in the *classpath* of the running task, so the classpath scanner is failing.

I have the dependencies of the task in the `project/plugins.sbt` file.

```
//adding the generation task dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.sksamuel.scapegoat" %% "scalac-scapegoat-plugin" % "1.3.4",
  "io.github.lukehutch" % "fast-classpath-scanner" % "2.18.1"
)
```

And I implemented the generation task in the `build.sbt` file:

```
//source generator task (simplified)
sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  //_root_ is needed because there is a sbt.io package in scope
  import _root_.io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.FastClasspathScanner
  import _root_.io.github.lukehutch.fastclasspathscanner.matchprocessor.SubclassMatchProcessor
  import com.sksamuel.scapegoat.Inspection
  import scala.collection.mutable

  val inspectionClass = classOf[Inspection]
  val fastCPScanner = new FastClasspathScanner(inspectionClass.getPackage.getName)
  val inspections = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[Inspection]
  fastCPScanner
    .matchSubclassesOf(
      inspectionClass,
      new SubclassMatchProcessor[Inspection] {
        override def processMatch(matchingClass: Class[_ <: Inspection]): Unit = {
          inspections += matchingClass.newInstance()
          println("Hello World")
        }
      }
    ).scan()

  val lines = inspections.toList.zipWithIndex map {
    case (inspection, idx) => s"${inspections.text} -> ${idx}"
  }

  val scapegoatInspectionsFile = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "scapegoat" / "inspections.scala"
  IO.writeLines(scapegoatInspectionsFile, lines)
  Seq(scapegoatInspectionsFile)
}.taskValue
```

**Note:** The task compiles and runs perfectly, the problem is that the generated file is empty, because the scanner finds no inspection. This can be confirmed because the `print("Hello world")` statement inside the `processMatch` method is not executed *(no output in the console)*.

Comment: `project/plugins.sbt` is used to specify plugins *for sbt* to be able to *build* your project, but not for the project itself. Could you please confirm have you put that code into `project/plugins.sbt` or just normal `build.sbt`? Most likely the only thing you need to do is to move it to `build.sbt`

Comment: @J0HN I updated the question to clarify more my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the scapegoat jar was indeed in the *classpath* of the task, but for some reason (that I don't understand) , probably related with the **sbt** classloader mechanism, the **fast-classpath-scanner** was failing to found them.

To anyone with a similar problem, to fix it you only need to override the scanner classloader.

```
 fastCPScanner
   .overrideClassLoaders(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
   (...)
   .scan()
```